# Java HttpGet doesn't accept gzip

Tags: java, android, http, http-headers

I am making an `HttpGet` to an url and I do not want the server to send the data `gzipped`. What `header` should I include in my `HttpGet` ?

With the default headers, the server sends gzipped data from time to time. I don't want this to happen. Thanks.

Comment: I should mention that the real problem was that the server was ignoring my `Accept-Encoding` header.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want the [Accept-Encoding](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.3) HTTP request header.

Update: per @Selvin's comment, leave it empty or set it to "identity".

Update: The web application has to cooperate properly to be HTTP compliant, of course.  If it's not honoring Accept-Encoding, look at its [Content-Encoding](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.11) HTTP response header.  If it's "gzip", just read the response body with Java's [GZIPInputStream.html](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/zip/GZIPInputStream.html).  Then add "gzip" to your Accept-Encoding request header, since your client now handles GZIP.  If the web application *doesn't* set the Content-Encoding header properly, that's another story altogether.

Comment: ... well i'm using Ad Muncher ... and it intercept http requests and remove gzip from Accept-Encoding (to get plain html, to get rid of ads)... anyway ... i saw that some server are fully compatible with RFC and some times send compressed data even if we tell it to not doing this

Answer (score 1):

You should set the **Accept-Encoding** header to **identity**.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to change the Accept-Encoding header, by removing the gzip|deflate value. If this doesn't work, you should also take into account that server doesn't care if the client supports the gzipped content (which is a bug and should be fixed).